# An efficient structure in which to keep a hash key and a collection of values

Tags: scala, collections

I am developing a stateful application. For the states I need a data structure that has a hash-key and a collection of values related to that key.

The collection should be efficient and occupy the least amount of memory possible. The collection should be mutable: items need to be removed or added.

Is there any such collection in Scala?

Comment: What is wrong with `mutable.Map[K,mutable.Set[V]]`?

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure you're looking for is a map with a nested collection:

```
Map[K, Set[V]]
```

Normally, it is considered a best practice to use immutable values:

```
val first_state: Map[String, Set[String]] = Map("A key" -> Set("Alpha", "Omega"))
val second_state = first_state + ("Another key" -> Set("Theta", "Iota"))
val third_state = second_state + ("Another key" -> Set("Kappa"))
```

The above results in the following values:

```
first_state: Map[String,Set[String]] = Map(A key -> Set(Alpha, Omega))
second_state: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Set[String]] = Map(A key -> Set(Alpha, Omega), Another key -> Set(Theta, Iota))
third_state: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Set[String]] = Map(A key -> Set(Alpha, Omega), Another key -> Set(Kappa))
```

We can see that your third state is exactly what you'd be looking for in this situation, and that you don't actually need mutable state to do what you're trying to do. [This post](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-add-update-remove-elements-immutable-maps-scala) shows a number of examples of how to manipulate immutable Maps, if you need more.

Note that Scala tries to *not* copy elements if it doesn't have to. Thus, while it seems like getting from `first_state` to `third_state` involves two complete copies, under the hood it does not. Unless you have a *specific* and *measured* performance problem, you should tend towards immutable state (in order to better ensure correctness). Given your current question there is nothing stated that suggests you need mutable state.